# Elemento fixed ter scroll

Tags: css

Como fazer uma div que entra na frente de um site (position: fixed;) ter scroll?

Veja um exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/caiocafardo/cj5gLt18/5/

Reparem que ao dar scroll só as divs de tras que sofrem o scroll... não sendo possível ler todo o texto do elemento fixed.

Comment: você tentou utilizar o overflow-y:scroll; no elemento que está fixed?

Comment: Sim, tentei... não acontece nada... https://jsfiddle.net/caiocafardo/cj5gLt18/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione apenas `overflow-y: scroll;` na class `.frente_fundo`

Comment: Não adianta... veja: https://jsfiddle.net/caiocafardo/cj5gLt18/5/

Comment: Peço desculpa, era scroll e não scoll. E não se esqueça do ponto e virgula no fim!